# Lock down site to authenticated users

Tags: users

How can you style the login page in drupal? I changed permissions to only allow authenticated users into the site but the login page is plain.

Comment: it should be otherwise how'd anonymous people login ?

Comment: What do you mean by login page is plain ? Would you like to change the css to make it better ?

Comment: Yes, if I don't allow anonymous users to view published content then they are presented with a login page. For that page how do you add images etc..